# Rails: How Do I Stop Amazon WorkMail Emails from going to Junk/Spam from my Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, smtp, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-workmail

I have a Rails 5.2 Heroku application that I changed to use my WorkMail Credentials using the documentation below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/userguide/using_IMAP_client.html

Here are my SMTP settings in config/application.rb.

```
# We are using Rails ActionMailers in this application
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  domain:               'www.mydomain.com',
  address:              ENV["SMTPADDRESS2"],
  port:                 465,
  user_name:            ENV["SMTPUSERNAME2"],
  password:             ENV["SMTPPASSWORD2"],
  tls:                  true,
  ssl:                  true,
  authentication:       'login' }
```

The contact form works but emails go into my junk folder instead of my inbox. I did not have this problem when I was using SES in my application. My email address was a GoDaddy POP account.

My application has from, reply-to and bcc set to my email address.

I set up an outbound rule to set both the sender and recipient to my email address. It did not work. I'm concerned about doing that since it could open up my email address to spoofing.

I also changed my SMTP settings to `authentication: 'plain'`. The email still went into my junk folder.

How can I solve this problem? Do I need to add something since WorkMail is an IMAP account? I wouldn't think that would matter since I'm only sending emails from the contact form.

UPDATED 03/02/2020 18:00

I decided to create a new GoDaddy POP account and change my SMTP settings to use Simple Email Service (SES) as before. The emails go to the inbox, not the junk folder. The problem I'm experiencing is unique to AWS WorkMail.